# How do you remove a listener IP from a SQL Availability Group Listener

Tags: sql

The title pretty much says it all.  I have an availability group that was a multi subnet, but now all replicas exist within a single subnet.  How do you remove the now redundant second IP.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878601.aspx

Seems to suggest you can only add IP, not remove.  Is dropping the listener and recreating it(ie an outage) really the only way of achieving this?

Answer (score 9):

You can remove Availability Group Listener IP addresses using Failover Cluster Manager.

1. Open Failover Cluster Manager
2. Connect to the Failover Cluster that hosts your SQL Availability Group
3. Navigate to Roles in the left pane and select you SQL Availability Group on the right-top pane
4. On the right bottom pane locate the select Resources tab
5. In the Resources tab, in the Server Name section right-click the item that says "Name: <*your-SQL-Availability-Group-Listener*>" and select Properties in the menu.
6. In the Properties window on the General tab select the IP address that you want to remove and click Remove button
7. Navigate to the dependencies tab, select the dependency that corresponds to your IP address and click Delete button.
8. Click OK to close the Properties window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not finding it in sys.availability_group_listener_ip_addresses (meaning you have removed it from failover cluster manager etc.. you will need to also remove it from each nodes registry under HKLM\Cluster\iSCSI Target\Portals.

Answer (score 0):

Remove is typically greyed out. You can remove it by removing it from the Windows Failover Cluster: Get-ClusterGroup WINCLUSTERNAME | Get-ClusterResource AAGNAME_IPTOREMOVE | Remove-ClusterResource